# Get Client ID and Client Secret of zoho crm sandbox

Tags: oauth, sandbox, zoho

Actually, I am facing some issues getting the client secret and client id and refresh token of my zoho crm sandbox environment.

I have already gotten my client secret and client id and refresh token for my prod environment.

Now I need to build my APIs in nodejs using zoho APIs.

So, for the testing environment, I need to set up my sandbox environment.

So, I am confused that from where I get the client secret and client id, and refresh token for my sandbox environment.
I have already built my sanbox environment I just need the client secret and client id and refresh token.

Please anyone guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the environment while [registering the client](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v5/register-client.html) in the API Console.

**1. Self Client:**

Once you enter the name and scope, it will ask for the environment. You can choose the Sandbox and proceed.

[image]

**2. Web-based Client:**

After creating clients like Server-based, when you make an [Authorization Request](https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v5/auth-request.html#redirection)
, you will be shown popup for selecting the environment.

[image]

Once the environment is chosen, the other steps are same for all. You can proceed similar to your production account.